# Connect to MySQL via ssh tunnel to localhost

Tags: mysql, ssh, localhost, tunnel

I want to connect to remote MySQL via ssh tunnel with user that has 'localhost' access.

I use this to make a tunnel:

```
ssh -f -N -L 33306:localhost:3306 user@remote-host
```

and this to connect to host:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 -uuser -ppassword
```

The error i get is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'remote-host' (using password: YES)
```

The problem is that user 'user'@'remote-host' (or 'user'@'%') does not exist, only 'user'@'localhost' does.

Is there a way to force remote host, **without server-side modifications** into thinking that i come from localhost? That's the only reason I would do the connection via ssh tunnel anyway.

---

*Note:*

If I want to connect with this command:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 33306 -uuser -ppassword
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

---

**Additional data:**

On remote server in /etc/hosts the values are like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
remote-ip       remote-host
```

Comment: This sounds fishy.  MySQL should already see the traffic `user@127.0.0.1`. Can you open the local port via telnet after establishing the tunnel?  `telnet localhost 33306` You should see something like `<junk>q>~mysql_native_password`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it says: [ales@host ~]$ telnet localhost 33306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
4
5.0.75? *Q/5ZJBK2,W?uQv|.kS<rJConnection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski our sysadmin told me that the tunnel here is useful for bypassing the firewall (no need to open additional ports) but that the mysql user 'user'@'%' should still exist.

Comment: @alesf did you verify that you used the correct pasword/user name and that you have permissions to connect to the database?

Comment: @schadr I suspect I did, but I asked this question more than two years ago and I don't really know how I solved it or if I did at all. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are treated differently in mysql on unix. 
Quoting:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html:

Furthermore, mysql client would silently try to use a socket file even if you explicitly specify -P on your command line:

> This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1

Effectively, using this command
`mysql -h localhost -P 33306 -uuser -ppassword`
you're simply trying to connect to your local mysqld which is missing

Considering this, your question boils down to connecting to a remote server available over a domain socket.

If installing additional software meets your requirements '**without server-side modifications**' you could use `socat` as described here:
https://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/68.

Tailored for mysql, it could work as follows:

1. install `socat` on both ends
2. `socat "UNIX-LISTEN:your_local_path/mysql.sock,reuseaddr,fork" EXEC:'ssh user@remote-host socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT\:/your_server_path/mysql.sock"`
3. `mysql -S your_local_path/mysql.sock -u user`

Answer (score 8):

The simple way to create MySQL Tunnel to REMOTE HOST:

```
$ ssh -fNL TEMP_PORT:localhost:MYSQL_SERVER_PORT USER@SERVER_NAME
```

Test:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P TEMP_PORT
```

Comment: simply brilliant way to connect to mysql with simple SSH TUNNEL and good ports. Legend